# Quadcopter: would putting 3 blades on the same level and the other blade below the first three work?

Tags: propeller, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, quadcopter, blade

Most quadcopters have their propeller blades all on the same level, or in some cases, a pair of blades placed a little above the other pair.

However, I was wondering if three propellers of a quadcopter can be put on the same level and the other propeller a little lower. Would it just make the quadcopter inefficient?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about a layout where a single propeller is in the center of the drone, and three other propellers are sticking out in a triangle shape?

Answer (score 2):

There are designs with overlapping blades. It's all a tradeoff on space, structure, clean aerodynamics, efficient aerodynamics, etc. This is the Malloy Hoverbike, for example.

[image]

So you can definitely have them at different levels, and you can even definitely have them overlap. If the 3 rotors' flow is not involved substantially with the 4th rotor's (not too big a difference in height), it should be no big deal.

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned a pair of blades higher and a pair lower, which your Hoverbike example shows. He's asking about 3 of the 4 being at level 1 and the 4th being at level 2.

Comment: The OP didn't mention an overlapping set, which was the point of the picture (all kinds of configurations possible). Updated answer to address your comment.